# Firefox is inconsistent on li element

Tags: firefox, css

[image: Error in FireFox]
[image: Correct in Internet explorer and Chrome]

_______________________EDIT_______________________

created an jsFiddle: [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ukbWE/)

_______________________EDIT_______________________

Hello,

I'm trying to fix this CSS bug, but i just cant see why this is happening!
Firefox is failing to show this correctly while other browsers show it correctly.

When i look to the divs, it appears that the Li is higher then in the other browsers.

Any ideas?

Here is my HTML and my CSS code.

**HTML**

```
  <ul class="popnav" >
            <li><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/add.png")" width="32" height="32" />      
                <ul class="SideNav popnav"  >                        
                                <li> @Html.ActionImage("Create", "Event", new { Type = 1 }, "~/Content/Images/icon_event_smaller.png", "New", "Appointment")

                               </li>   

                                <li> @Html.ActionImage("Create", "Event", null, "~/Content/Images/task_smaller.png", "New", "Task")

                               </li>
                                <li> @Html.ActionImage("Create", "Document", null, "~/Content/Images/doc_smaller.png", "New", "Document")

                                </li>       
                                <li> @Html.ActionImage("Create", "Company", null, "~/Content/Images/comp_smaller.png", "New", "Company")</li>   
                                <li> @Html.ActionImage("Create", "Contact", null, "~/Content/Images/person_smaller.png", "New", "Contact")</li>                   

                </ul>
                <div class="clear"></div>
<li></li> 
....
```

**CSS**

```
     *
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Sans-serif;
    color: #404040;
}
  .clear
    {
        clear: both;
    }
    /* remove the list style */
    .popnav
    {
    }

    /* make the LI display inline */
    /* it's position relative so that position absolute */
    /* can be used in submenu */
    .popnav li
    {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 500;
    }

    .popnav li ul li:hover
    {
        background-color: #45a6cf;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
        box-shadow: inset 0 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    .popnav li ul li:hover a
    {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.0s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.0s ease-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.0s ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.0s ease-out;
        color: White;
    }

    .popnav li ul li:hover .SideSubNav a
    {
        color: #404040;
    }
    .popnav li ul li:hover .SideSubNav a:hover
    {
        color: White;
    }
    /* this is the parent menu */
    .popnav li a
    {
        display: block;
        height: 23px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: 8px;
        text-shadow: none;
        color: #404040;
    }

    #main #col1 ul li img
    {
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
    #bNav .popnav li img
    {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

Comment: Are you starting with a "reset.css" that normalizes the defaults across browsers?

Comment: what happens if you remove the clearing div?

Comment: Yeah, i use this the reset css (i guess?) is this simular to *
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Sans-serif;
    color: #404040;
} ?

Comment: when i remove the clearing div, nothing mutch happens.

Comment: Can you link to the page, or make a test case? http://jsbin.com/ / http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: you are missing a closing tag maybe? make you code html valid otherwise browser do what they want

Comment: You talk about setting the li to relative so that you can use absolute positioning, but then you're not using absolute positioning anywhere. I'm suspicious of your inline width and height; and even if they're not the culprits you should relegate this to your CSS.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle example. [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ukbWE/)

Comment: You have far, far too many divs for this. Your `*{}` is going about things in the wrong way, too, but that's the subject for another question.

Comment: Great to have a fiddle, but since it doesn't correspond to the screenshot, I'm not longer sure what needs doing.

Comment: Thx Greg for you comment, i cleaned out the css to create this jsFiddle. But this seemed to solve the problem in some way. Because now FireFox and Chrome are showing the same result... I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to set a fixed height for `.popnav li`, this way you should resolve quickly. In other cases you may want to **reset** your CSS.

Every browser has different default settings in the visual representation of HTML elements. For this reason it is very useful to implement a CSS reset that removes and neutralizes the inconsistent default browser styling settings.

The [Eric Meyer's CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) is one of the most popular, but you can always find other solutions by looking on search engines.

Comment: the wildcard reset he's using should cover pretty much everything that any other reset would.

Comment: Browsers generally have the same values for most of their elements. Fixing this may just be a matter of adjust that one element.

Comment: anny ideas Rob? I used that reset.css, but it didnt change a thing.